# Как вытащить значение из INI-файла?

Tags: c#, ini

Есть файл `profiles.ini` в нём существует строчка, содержащая путь до некоторой папки, например:

> ```
> Path=Profiles/6tk25599.default
> ```

Как мне прочитать файл и добраться до этого значения?

Вот всё содержимое файла:

> ```
> [General]
> StartWithLastProfile=1
>
> [Profile0]
> Name=default
> IsRelative=1
> Path=Profiles/6tk25599.default
> Default=1
> ```

В итоге я хочу получить путь: `Profiles/6tk25599.default`

Попробовал такой метод:

```
foreach (var str in File.ReadLines("profiles.ini").Skip(6).Take(1))
{
   Console.WriteLine(str); // получаю путь:  Path=Profiles/6tk25599.default
}
```

Comment: А зачем Вам вся эта конструкция, когда то же самое делается с помощью `Console.WriteLine(File.ReadLines("profiles.ini")[6])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот, что Вам необходимо сделать:

```
foreach (string x in File.ReadAllLines("profiles.ini"))
{
    string[] data = x.Split('=');
    if (data.Length == 2 && data[0] == "Path")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(data[1]); // Вывод: Profiles/6tk25599.default
        break;
    }
}
```

1. Проходимся по всем строчкам из нужного Вам файла
2. Делим строчку по символу '='
3. Если "ключ" равняется нужному Вам "Path", то выводим значение в консоль и останавливаем цикл

---

**UPD**: Судя по обновлению Вашего вопроса, строка всегда остается на одной позиции. Так что все еще проще:

```
Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllLines("profiles.ini")[6].Split('=')[1]);
```

---

**UPD2**: Как заметил @Андрей, лучше использовать метод `File.ReadLines`, чтобы не хранить в памяти всю коллекцию строк. Так что обновляю ответ

Вариант для извлечения из изначально `неизвестной` строки:

```
File.ReadLines("profiles.ini").First(x => x.StartsWith("Path=")).Split('=')[1];
```

Вариант для извлечения из изначально `известной` строки:

```
File.ReadLines("profiles.ini").ElementAt(6).Split('=')[1];
```

Comment: Если файл большой, для выдергивания одной строчки может быть накладно загружать его в память полностью, поэтому лучше использовать `File.ReadLines` вместо `File.ReadAllLines`. Во втором случае тогда, вместо доступа по индексу можно использовать Linq-операцию `ElementAt`

Comment: Деревянный способ, если честно.

Comment: @And Я не думаю, что для извлечения одного значения стоит прибегать к чему-то `не` деревянному

Comment: Если в значении будут знаки равенства, у тебя проблемы. А ещё ты имя секции вообще не учитываешь.

Comment: @Qwertiy У FAT-файловых систем знак равенства вообще является запрещённым символом для имени файлов) Да и товарищ вопрошающий не просил учитывать имя секции) Я не спорю, что метод не идеальный, но для выполнения указанной задачи его более чем достаточно)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, с чего бы знак равенства был запрещён? У меня на флешке FAT32 - `=` отлично работает. И вообще, почему никто никогда не положит программу на NTFS?

Comment: @Qwertiy А, прошу извинить, написано, что данные символы (‘+ , ; = [ ]’) не разрешены только для файлов с короткими названиями)

Answer (score 10):

Не уважаете вы ini файлы, да, устарели, но е мое, это тоже ведь придуманный человеком формат, такой же как XML или JSON, в свое время был очень популярным, да что там, даже сейчас часто где еще есть.

Так вот, с файлом надо работать как положено и для этого есть специальные инструменты в самой Windows! Создайте примерно такой класс [источник](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1966/An-INI-file-handling-class-using-C) и работайте как положено! :

```
public class IniFile
{
    public string path;

    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    private static extern long WritePrivateProfileString(string section,
        string key, string val, string filePath);
    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string section,
        string key, string def, StringBuilder retVal,
        int size, string filePath);


    public IniFile(string iniPath)
    {
        path = iniPath;
    }

    public void IniWriteValue(string section, string key, string value)
    {
        WritePrivateProfileString(section, key, value, path);
    }

    public string IniReadValue(string section, string key)
    {
        StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(255);
        int i = GetPrivateProfileString(section, key, "", temp, 255, path);
        return temp.ToString();
    }
}
```

Далее нам достаточно написать:

```
IniFile ini = new IniFile(@"D:\test.ini");
var result = ini.IniReadValue("Profile0", "Path");
```

Comment: Слишком громоздко)) А чем Ваш пример отличается от примера который привёл @Kir_Antipov ?!

Comment: @GooliveR Мой пример ориентирован на конкретно Вашу задачу, а пример EvgeniyZ позволяет быстро работать с любым ini файлом. Признаться, я даже и не знал, что в WinAPI есть встроенные методы для этого) Так что штука полезная)

Comment: @GooliveR Ну вот нужен вам дома газ, вы берете, заместо того, чтоб платить правительству покупаете балон газовый и им пользуетесь, в какой то момент он может так бахнуть, что мало не покажется. Тут я думаю также, вам решать что и как использовать, я лишь указал **правильный** способ работы с данным форматом, а не кустарный...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ А для каких-нибудь еще типов файлов существуют встроенные методы подобной обработки информации?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Если говорить об API, то вроде только ini, ибо этот формат издавна придуман самими Microsoft для Windows, вся система на них была построена раньше. Сейчас все на XML и JSON переходят, но они поддерживаются на уровне самого C#.

Comment: Этот код жутко неэффективен и будет ради каждого параметра читать файл целиком (ну или, как минимум, до вхождения этого параметра - не уверен точно).

Comment: @Qwertiy Я считаю сам ini не эффективным форматом в целом... Здесь лишь показал первый попавшийся пример грамотного чтения данного формата. По скорости - это как по мне уже отдельный вопрос, да и всегда есть возможность поставить сторонние библиотеки в которых учли те или иные аспекты.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, правильный вариант - прочитать файл, распарсить и держать в памяти как двумерный словарь. Не важно, это в готовой библиотеке или самописное. Но если у тебя 100 параметров, то 100 раз читать весь файл - это какая-то жесть и совершенно точно производительность (предполагаю чтение настроек при запуске) пострадает.

Comment: А эти winapi идут корнями в win 3.1, когда был единственный ini-файл на все программы, а его секция принадлежала программе. Очевидно, что это вообще не было рассчитано на наличие кучи параметров и их эффективное чтение.

Comment: Хочу спросить а что делает эта строка: `int i = GetPrivateProfileString(section, key, "", temp, 255, path);` ? тип `int i =` должен куда-то передаваться? Или это просто опечатка =) и там должен быть `return i.ToString();` за место `return temp.ToString();`

Comment: Попробовал Ваш способ, пробую читать из файла, но получаю только числа 25.  Читаю это значение: `"Profile0", "Path"`

Comment: @GooliveR Вы можете почитать про данную функцию [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms724353(v=vs.85).aspx), выходным значением будет размер значения, которое получили из ini файла. В данном случае можно убрать присвоение (`int i =`) и оставить только вызов самой функции. Сама же функция на вход получает temp - это то, куда она запишет полученное значение.

Answer (score 1):

Как верно заметил @EvgeniyZ в соседнем ответе, для разбора файлов в специализированных форматах нужно использовать средства предназначенные для этого, т. к. при "ручном" парсинге можно запросто забыть учесть какой-то нюанс.

Я на вашем месте подключил бы какую-нибудь библиотеку и воспользовался ей, например можно использовать [ini-parser](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ini-parser/):

```
using IniParser;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var filepath = @"...\Test.ini";
        var parser = new FileIniDataParser();
        var iniData = parser.ReadFile(filepath);
        var sectionName = "Profile0";
        var keyName = "Path";
        var value = iniData[sectionName][keyName];
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

Преимущество этого подхода перед использованием WinAPI — отсутствие зависимости от платформы и большее удобство.

Comment: При подключении _какой-нибудь_ библиотеки стоит узнать, а не накосячил ли в ней автор. Впрочем, сам подход вроде верный - один раз прочитать файл, распарсить и держать в памяти как двумерный словарь.

Comment: А что есть подозрения? Я не изучал особо, можно сказать взял первую попавшуюся более-менее свежую и попробовал.

Comment: Нет, не смотрел её. Просто по опыту - косяки во всяких библиотеках весьма вероятны.

Comment: Косяки в своем коде более вероятны, чем больше пользователей, тем больше багов должно быть выловлено.

Comment: Ну это-то да. Хотя и не всегда...