# С# Как считать данные после слова в строке

Tags: c#

Считывается строка 6, мне нужно что после слова AUTHENTIC_DOMAIN= **считывался адрес
AUTHENTIC_DOMAIN=127.0.0.1**

Вот сама строчка в коде File.ReadLines(@"service.ini").ElementAt(6);

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вытащить значение из INI-файла?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/837253/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-ini-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я отвечу, не на этот вопрос, а на другой. Который, собственно, автора интересует больше чем этот -- "как читать/обрабатывать данные в INI файлах?"

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace BotAgent.DataExporter
{
    public class Ini
    {
        public string Path;

        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        private static extern long WritePrivateProfileString(string section,
            string key, string val, string filePath);
        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string section,
                 string key, string def, StringBuilder retVal,
            int size, string filePath);

        public Ini(string iniPath)
        {
            Path = iniPath;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Works with "Default" section
        /// </summary>
        public void Write(string key, string value)
        {
            WritePrivateProfileString("Default", key, value, Path);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Write Data to the INI File
        /// </summary>
        /// <PARAM name="section"></PARAM>
        /// section name
        /// <PARAM name="key"></PARAM>
        /// key Name
        /// <PARAM name="value"></PARAM>
        /// value Name
        public void Write(string section, string key, string value)
        {
            WritePrivateProfileString(section, key, value, Path);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Works with "Default" section
        /// </summary>
        public string Read(string key)
        {
            StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(255);
            int i = GetPrivateProfileString("Default", key, "", temp, 255, Path);
            return temp.ToString();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Read Data value From the Ini File
        /// </summary>
        /// <PARAM name="section"></PARAM>
        /// <PARAM name="key"></PARAM>
        /// <PARAM name="Path"></PARAM>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string Read(string section, string key)
        {
            StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(255);
            int i = GetPrivateProfileString(section, key, "", temp, 255, Path);
            return temp.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Код взят отсюда:
https://github.com/ukushu/DataExporter/

---

**Ну а если уж отвечать на этот то:**

- если это гарантированно начало строки то:

`var a = someString.SubString(17, someString.Length - 17);`

- Если же значение посередине строки, то здесь уже нужно регулярные выражения использовать. Гугли по Regex C#

Comment: Дело не в этом, дело в том что я не знаю как мне считать данные в 6 строке после Слова AUTHENTIC_DOMAIN=    Но я знаю как просто считать 6-ую строку

Comment: Я ответил и на этот вопрос -- вторая часть, после подчеркивания. Но лучше присмотрись к по-настоящему нужной тебе части -- она идет сначала. Поверь, первая часть ответа тебе нужнее ;)

Comment: Не совсем понимаю как это применить

Comment: Строка идет так           -  textBoxServerIP.Text = File.ReadLines(@"service.ini").ElementAt(6);

Comment: Создаешь класс, всовуешь туда весь этот код а потом используешь его  ```var domain = IniInstance.Read("НазваниеСекции", "AUTHENTIC_DOMAIN");``` и получаешь только значение из даного ини файла

Comment: Можно и без класса это я точно знаю, просто я уже не могу вспомнить как это сделать в одну строку и проще

Comment: Серьезно, давай на чистоту, не "не могу вспомнить" а "не знаю и никогда не знал". Подойди до преподавателя и пусть он тебе обьяснит мой ответ... Чесно, я написал в 100 раз более развернутый ответ чем того требовалось. Если ты не понимаешь как это применить, то это уже недочет или твоих стараний в учебе или стараний твоего преподавателя(в чем я сомневаюсь). Лучше чем с применеием этого класса ты не напишешь. И пусть преподаватель тебе обьясняет почему так.

Comment: Как удалить слово "AUTHENTIC_DOMAIN="  из переменной ServerIP

Comment: ```ServerIP  = ServerIP.Replace("AUTHENTIC_DOMAIN=", "");```

Comment: Спасибо большое