# Что означает "Функция должна выполнять одно и только одно действие"?

Tags: c#, .net-4.8

Тезис из заголовка самим автором разъясняется, на сколько я знаю, так: "Если функция выполняет только те действия, которые находятся на одном уровне абстракции под объявленным именем функции, то эта функция выполняет одну операцию".
Так как программировать я учусь недавно(2 месяца), то прошу знающих людей объяснить, как это должно выглядеть на простом примере:

Есть метод (вызываемый из метода Main), принимающий две строки и возвращающий третью строку, содержащую текст, который не встречается в исходных строках (на деле чуть сложнее, но для примера сойдет и такое объяснение).
Внутри метода исходные строки разбиваются на два списка по определенному ключевому слову, затем определяется пересечение двух списков и поочередно удаляется из каждого. Далее создаются два словаря, они сравниваются по заголовкам, и их содержимое добавляется в StringBuilder, а затем возвращается из метода в виде одной строки.

По сути, этот метод выполняет одно действие - находит различия между строками. Но внутри он выполняет несколько разных действий, а потому меня интересует, как можно правильно оформить такой метод, и нужно ли пытаться это сделать. Мне это представляется следующим образом:

1. Вместо одного метода их должно быть несколько. Первый вызывается из метода Main, а все остальные вызываются им самим;
2. Все функции (создание списков, поиск пересечений, удаление пересечений, создание словарей и т.д.) должны быть оформлены в отдельные (дочерние) методы, вызываемые в оперделенном порядке из первого.
   В результате в первом методе будет содержаться только перечисление отдельных действий, а сами действия будут подробно расписаны в отдельных методах.

На словах выглядит хорошо, только вот первый метод принимает 4 аргумента, и вызов дочерних методов потребует передачи каждому из них этих аргументов. В результате получается ни сколько не короче и не чище...
Выходом было бы не создавать отдельные методы, а оформить их в виде локальных функций первого - тогда они смогли бы использовать его аргументы. Либо вынести используемые аргументы в поля класса.

Ещё что-то слышал про передачу нескольких аргументов через параметр object, но как это правильно делается не знаю.

Вот такой пример. Прошу знающих людей подсказать, как правильно оформлять такой или подобный код, чтобы голова не начинала болеть после первого прочтения)) Заранее спасибо!

Метод Main:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Введите путь к исходному файлу реестра: ");

        string originalRegistry = File.ReadAllText(Console.ReadLine().Replace("\"", ""));

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("Введите путь к измененному файлу реестра: ");

        string modifiedRegistry = File.ReadAllText(Console.ReadLine().Replace("\"", ""));

        Console.WriteLine();

        string paragraphSeparator = "[HKEY";
        string keyValueSeparator = "\r\n";

        File.WriteAllText("RegistryTweaks.reg", FindDifferencesBetweenFiles(originalRegistry, modifiedRegistry, paragraphSeparator, keyValueSeparator));

        Console.WriteLine("Готово!");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Метод для анализа входных текстовых файлов:

```
        static string FindDifferencesBetweenFiles(string originalRegistry, string modifiedRegistry, string paragraphSeparator, string keyValueSeparator)
    {
        var originalList = originalRegistry.Split(new string[] { paragraphSeparator }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();
        var modifiedList = modifiedRegistry.Split(new string[] { paragraphSeparator }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();

        var intersection = originalList.Intersect(modifiedList).ToList();

        intersection.ForEach(item => originalList.RemoveAt(originalList.IndexOf(item)));
        intersection.ForEach(item => modifiedList.RemoveAt(modifiedList.IndexOf(item)));

        var originalDictionary = originalList.ToDictionary(item => paragraphSeparator + item.Substring(0, item.IndexOf(keyValueSeparator)), item => paragraphSeparator + item);
        var modifiedDictionary = modifiedList.ToDictionary(item => paragraphSeparator + item.Substring(0, item.IndexOf(keyValueSeparator)), item => paragraphSeparator + item);

        var builder = new StringBuilder("Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00\r\n\r\n");

        modifiedDictionary.Values.ToList().ForEach(item => builder.Append(item));

        foreach (string originalDictionaryKey in originalDictionary.Keys)
        {
            if (!modifiedDictionary.ContainsKey(originalDictionaryKey))
            {
                builder.Append(originalDictionary[originalDictionaryKey].Insert(1, "-"));
            }
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

Пример данных, с которыми работает программа:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\RESOURCEMAP\System Resources]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\RESOURCEMAP\System Resources\Loader Reserved]
".Raw"=hex(8):01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,0b,00,00,00,03,\
    0e,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,03,01,00,00,00,20,10,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,70,09,00,00,00,00,0064,03,01,00,00,00,00,d0,09,00,00,00,00,00,00,30,00,\
          
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\RESOURCEMAP\System Resources\Physical Memory]
".Translated"=hex(8):01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,09,00,00,\
  00,03,01,00,00,00,10,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,c0,09,00,00,00,00,00,03,01,00,00,\
  00,00,10,00,00,00,00,00,00,24640,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,01,00,00,00,30,10,00,00,\
        00,50,c8,db,00,00,00,00,00,10,18,00,00,00,00,00,03,01,00,00,00,e0,d7,dc,00,\
  00,00,00,00,20,28,02,00,00,00,00,07,01,00,02,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,38,\
  1f,03,00,00,00,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\RESOURCEMAP\System Resources\Reserved]
".Translated"=hex(8):01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,\
  00,03,01,00,00,00,10,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,c0,09,00,00,00,00,00,03,01,00,00,\
  00,30,10,00,00,00,00,00,00,60,09,00,00,00,00,00
```

Если ключ (строка, начинающаяся на "[HKEY" и до символа переноса "\r\n") отсутствует в измененном файле реестра, значит этот ключ вместе с содержимым нужно добавить в итоговый файл, добавив к нему "-" ("[-HKEY");

Если ключ вместе с содержимым* присуствует обоих анализируемых файлах без изменений, то он игнорируется (в выходной файл попасть не должен);

Если ключ присуствует в обоих анализируемых файлах, но содержимое отличается, то в итоговый файл нужно поместить этот ключ вместе с содержимым из измененного снимка реестра.

Comment: Хотелось бы видеть файлы и что должно быть на выходе. И без "абстракций", а по существу, ибо вы работаете с реестром, а говорите "о тексте", это только путает... А так, у вас в методе не одна задача выполняется, а как минимум 2. Первая - Получение данных, тех самых "словарей", а вторая задача - формирование новой строки на основе этих данных.

Comment: Что Вы имеете ввиду под "Увидеть файлы"? Могу добавить код метода Main, но там просто открываются два тектовых файла и отправляются в уже опубликованный метод. Или выложить само решение? Сама программа для работы с реестром винды (цель - получение готовых твиков путем сравнения двух разных снимков).

Comment: `Есть метод (вызываемый из метода Main), принимающий две строки и возвращающий третью строку, содержащую текст, который не встречается в исходных строках (на деле чуть сложнее, но для примера сойдет и такое объяснение).` - так не пойдет. Чтобы начать понимать принципы, вам надо сначала пояснить назначение кода, зачем он существует? Пример типа "берем строку и сравниваем" - это то как метод уже написан. Перед такими детялями поясните что за проблему код решает, что он получает на входе и выходе, а потом уже можем говорить о том, хорошо ли он написан.

Comment: А что не понятного в "Увидеть файлы"? Сами ведь пишете "открываются два тектовых файла" - вы в них что-то ищете, что-то делаете, на выход отдаете что-то, то есть вы видите эти файлы на основе которых уже пишете код. Я например, их не вижу, и для написания моего кода, у меня допустим нету всех данных, а значит, можно только фантазировать на тему "как правильно". Вот я и прошу от вас **данные**, на основе которых можно будет писать код. Мне не нужны 100500 строк текста, достаточно добавить в сам вопрос ~5 входных из каждого файла и что должно быть на выходе.

Comment: У меня в принципе замечаний к методу нет, за исключением того что он кучу лишних копирований данных делает, вследствие чего медленно работает. Я бы как-то так переписал https://pastebin.com/51pt3GUB Ну и 4.8 сам по себе тормоз, на .NET 8 можно ещё раз в 5 быстрее это написать. А дальше, нужно разбирать на примерах, что и как должно работать. `ToList()` - зло. Ещё есть ощущение, что надо сначала удалять старые ключи, а затем добавлять новые, а не наоборот.

Comment: ну то есть у вас есть работа для 1) считывания файлов в какой то объект типа набора ключей/значений реестра 2) поиск различий между наборами ключей/значений (а не просто по тексту) 3) формат этих различий в вид, подходящий для эеспорта 4) Экспорт различий в выходной файл. То есть как минимум 4 функции, у вас только одна.

Comment: Можно узнать, почему ToList() - зло?
Словари нужны только для сравнения ключей отдельно от значений. Можно было бы их не использовать и сравнивать сами списки, используя Substring, но код тогда получился бы два экрана в длину, поэтому решил перекинуть в словари.
tym32167 - меня это и смущает, но я пока смутно представляю, как это организовать правильно. Примерные представления есть - я их изложил в самом вопросе. Если можете конкретно подсказать, буду признателен. Не нужно перечислять - то сюда, это сюда - просто опишите принцип организации, а я дальше соображу.

Comment: @JamesBond вы берете массив и копируете его в список, который далее не изменяете, материализация перечислений - тоже лишнее копирование, выделение памяти + затраты времени на операцию. Ради цикла ForEach точно списки не стоит делать к тому же вы создаете лишний стрелочный делегат, когда используя стандартный цикл можно обойтись без него, как-то так.

Comment: @JamesBond поправил выше ссылку на код с исправлениями после ваших пояснений.

Comment: Первая версия кода, построенная целиком на циклах foreach, по моим подсчетам анализировала бы данные файлы около 12 часов))) Поэтому стал искать более быстрые варианты, и решение с выявлением пересечений оказалось самым быстрым. Ну а после удаления найденных пересечений можно было бы уже любым методом пользоваться, т.к. дальше анализируются только ключи, да и сами файлы заметно "похудевшие".

Comment: А вы сравните по скорости свою и мою версию)

Comment: Сравнил. Метод Except мне попадался, но я видимо неправильно понял принцип его работы, поэтому не использовал - я думал, что он только удаляет дубликаты. А так да - удаление пересечений это как раз самая долгая операция, у меня занимала 40 секунд. А так всего 2. Спасибо за подсказку)
Ну а с самим кодом, считаете, ничего делать не нужно? Тут выше писали, что разные операции выполняются и т.п. Я собственно, именно об этом и спрашивал...

Comment: ИМХО, метод совершенно некорректен. 1. Метод называется `FindDifferencesBetweenFiles`, а значит логика у него должна быть: получить на вход **пути** до файлов, прочитать их, сравнить их, отдать наружу **разницу**, ну а вы все смешали в одну кучу. 2. Исходя из первого, у вас должен быть метод чтения и "парсинга" файла, далее метод получения разницы, ну и далее метод формирования `.reg` файла на основе этой разницы. 3. `.reg` файл это `.ini` формат, придумывать свои костыли не лучшая идея, лучше использовать [готовое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/837259/220553) и сравнивать потом просто ключи.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ благодарю! Обдумаю, как это применить. В кучу смешал, т.к. напомню, учусь всего два месяца, сделал как умею. Готовое решение не взял, т.к. мне сейчас важнее практика, а на этой программке можно было и потренироваться писать код, и поучиться писать тесты. Ну и ещё в готовых решениях не было гарантии, что автор не решил вывести из под анализа какие-либо ветки реестра, а я хотел проанализировать всё. По поводу .ini формата не совсем понял...

Comment: Ну вот смотрите, вы строите например дом, неужели для этого вы будете делать свой молоток, пилу, другой инструмент? Думаю нет. Аналогично и тут, вы "строите" свой проект, неужели будете изобретать весь C#? Если да, то тогда вам стоит отказаться от `LINQ`, от `foreach`, от `File.Read...()` и от кучи чего еще, начав это "изобретать" самостоятельно. Согласитесь, такое себе, да? Ну так почему формат файла, который кем-то был изобретен и описан, вы вдруг руками перебираете, а не используете специальные для этого инструменты?

Comment: Ну а если вы `.ini` (напомню `.reg` это `.ini` формат, только с заголовком сверху) всеж хотите руками разбирать, то тогда и тут у вас оплошность, очень много странных действий, ибо формат состоит из "секции", в которой уже идут "Ключ" и "Значение". Вот я на вашем месте  читал-бы все строки, а потом перегонял это в класс, содержащий в себе свойства секции, ключа, значения (можно словарь применить), а уже на основе этого сверял значения. Сейчас у вас вообще странно, например зачем-то используете разбитие по `[HKEY`. Короче, подумайте над этим всем)

Comment: Про .ini формат и его структуру я ничего не знаю, потому и работаю просто как с текстом. А по поводу аналогии со строительством - строить я только учусь) И во время обучения часто так и поступают - показывают изучаемые объекты в разрезе. Замахиваться на форматы и использование их индивидуальных особенностей мне пока рано, надо язык выучить сначала. Ну а задачка с анализом файлов реестра - отличная возможность отработать на практике добрую половину всего изученного - работу со строками, коллекциями, циклами и динамическими методами. Так что считаю, что я все делаю правильно.

Comment: `Замахиваться на форматы и использование их индивидуальных особенностей мне пока рано` - но вы это делаете. Ваш `.reg` - это `.ini`, и вместо использования готового инструмента, вы изобретаете свой, с нуля, когда как говорите "рано" ) Что касается "разрез" - все это в отрытом доступе и видно как работает. Не, ну дело ваше конечно, просто говорю, тогда не используйте `foreach`, всякие `File.Read()` и так далее, познаете еще как и итерацию делать, как работать с байтами и т.д., полезно, да. Короче, дело ваше, спорить не буду. Проблемные места (на мой взгляд) я указал. Удачи!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ благодарю за подсказки! Foreach и всякие File.Read() - это инструменты языка, который я учу. Особенности конкретного формата данных, работу с которыми, строго говоря, в изучаемом мною курсе ещё даже не начали - это тема значительно более узкая. Ну и о том, что .reg это .ini я узнал от Вас, а программа уже написана, и функцию свою выполняет...) Ну и ещё - я потому изначально и не выложил код в самом вопросе, потому что обычно это превращается в обсуждение конкретного кода и конкретных решений, а меня интересовал обобщенный ответ на обобщенный вопрос.

Comment: К вопросу о выбранном алгоритме. Если данные в файлах упорядочены по ключу, то использование dictionary (или чего-то подобного) избыточно. Достаточно последовательно читать оба файла и сравнивать ключи из них (естественно, максимальная эффективность достигается при посимвольном сравнении ключей прямо во время чтения файлов). Т.о. вся работа может быть выполнена за время их чтения. (Для иллюстрации может посмотореть на широкоизвестную процедуру слияния двух отсортированных массивов. Суть та же)

Comment: Чтобы данные были упорядочены по ключу, думаю, их нужно опорядочивать)) Всё таки файлы сравниваются именно потому, что в них присутствуют изменения, а изменения эти нарушают порядок. Поэтому мне кажется, что хочешь не хочешь, а от предварительного поиска ключей никуда не деться. Dictionary использован только чтобы отделить ключи от содержимого, и не нарушить при этом порядок элементов в коллекции

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот простое объяснение.

Метод что делает?

- Сплитит строку на части
- Создает 2 словаря
- Скармливает словари билдеру

Это можно подвести под одну общую стадию обработки данных, здесь именно логически разбивать метод нет смысла.

По стадиям обработки - 2 этапа: парсинг и сборка. Но разбивать был бы смысл, если бы промежуточные данные между этими этапами нужны были бы где-то ещё.

Итого, я рекомендую оставить как есть.

---

Раз уж написал ответ, вот немного ускоренная версия метода

```
static string FindDifferencesBetweenFiles(string originalRegistry, string modifiedRegistry, string paragraphSeparator, string keyValueSeparator)
{
    var separator = new string[] { paragraphSeparator };
    var original = originalRegistry.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.None);
    var modified = modifiedRegistry.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.None);
 
    var originalDictionary = original.Except(modified).ToDictionary(item => paragraphSeparator + item.Substring(0, item.IndexOf(keyValueSeparator)), item => item);
    var modifiedDictionary = modified.Except(original).ToDictionary(item => paragraphSeparator + item.Substring(0, item.IndexOf(keyValueSeparator)), item => item);
 
    var builder = new StringBuilder("Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00\r\n\r\n");
 
    foreach (var item in originalDictionary.Values)
    {
        builder.Append(paragraphSeparator).Append(item);
    }
 
    var paragraphRemoveSeparator = paragraphSeparator.Insert(1, "-");
    foreach (var originalDictionaryPair in originalDictionary)
    {
        if (!modifiedDictionary.ContainsKey(originalDictionaryPair.Key))
        {
            builder.Append(paragraphRemoveSeparator).Append(originalDictionaryPair.Value);
        }
    }
 
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

---

Если же исходить из обработки структуры данных реестра системы, то я бы делал полную симуляцию базы реестра на основе какой-то БД типа SQLite, это не космически сложно. И работал уже бы с полностью детализированными данными, а не строками.

Скажем так, ваша реализация очень грубая и узконаправленная. Понимаю, что это сделано в первую очередь для производительности, но здесь уже вопрос в том - как именно вы собираетесь приложение развивать. Вообще можно начать и напрямую с реестром работать, это может оказаться ещё быстрее.

Comment: Благодарю за детальный ответ! Ну, о развитии приложения пока не задумывались, да и приложение - это сильно сказано. Так, учебный эксперимент, плюс попытка получить способ автоматической настройки винды после переустановки (неудачный). Поначалу была мысль попытаться анализировать реестр и диск на предмет всех изменений при установке программ, чтобы потом лепить из них приложения типа Portable, но не уверен, что тут можно обойтись одним копированием...

Comment: И ещё, не могли бы Вы, раз уж упомянули об этом, объяснить, почему ToList() с Вашей точки зрения это зло? Ибо я этими приведениями пользуюсь на постоянной основе, и хотел бы знать...

Comment: @JamesBond потому что происходит копирование данных, дублирование. Это в целом не зло, зло это то, как вы это используете. То же самое с `ToArray()`. Но массив хотя-бы более легковесный и быстрее в циклах итерируется.

Comment: Понял, благодарю!